# Consider the multiplicative group $S = \{z:|z| = 1\}$, a subset of $C$. Let $G$ and $H$ be subgroups of $S$.Find order of intersection of $G$ and $H$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Consider the multiplicative group $S = \{z:|z| = 1\}$, a subset of $C$. Let $G$ and $H$ be subgroups of order $8$ and $10$ respectively. Find order of intersection of $G$ and $H$.

Since $1$ and $2$ both divide $8$ and $10$ so, order must be one of them.

What is the order$?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be $2$ as $\{\pm 1\}\subseteq G\cap H$.

Notice that, $G$ has order $8$ implies each element of $G$ satisfies $x^8-1=0$. So $8$ distinct elements of $G$ satifies the polynomial $x^8-1\in \Bbb C[x]$ and this polynomial has exactly $8$ roots, namely $\big\{e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{8}}:k=1,...,8\big\}$.  Hence, $G=\big\langle e^{\frac{2i\pi}{8}}\big\rangle$ and similarly $H=\big\langle e^{\frac{2i\pi}{10}}\big\rangle$.

Now, $-1=\big(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{8}}\big)^4\in G$ and $-1=\big(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{10}}\big)^{5}\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the exact sequence
$$\{1\}\longrightarrow G\cap H\longrightarrow G\times H\longrightarrow GH\longrightarrow\{1\}, $$
where $G\times H  \longrightarrow GH$ maps $(g,h)$ onto $gh^{-1}$. The exactness of this sequence implies that $|G\times H|=|G\cap H|\cdot |GH|$, so you just have to determine the order of the subgroup $GH$. As $G$ and $H$ are cyclic, of orders $8$ and $10$ respectively, you can show that $GH$ is cyclic, of order $\operatorname{lcm}(8,10)$.

Comment: +1 from me, for alternative way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The circle group $S$ has the property that for every $n\in\Bbb N_{>0}$ it has a *unique* subgroup of order$~n$, which is the cyclic group $C_n=\{\,z\in S \mid z^n=1\,\}$. Also one has $C_d\subseteq C_n\iff d\mid n$, which accounts for *all* subgroups of $C_n$ as such subgroups are also subgroups of $S$. It follows that whenever $d$ divides $n$ and $m$ one has $C_d\subseteq C_n\cap C_m$, and hence that $C_n\cap C_m=C_{\gcd(n,m)}$.